# Control-M binding with Integration Server

Tags: automation, cruisecontrol.net, control-m

I know its very rare to think of that but , is there a way to link BMC Control-M with Cruise Control.Net server ? Is there a Control-M command line or executable to use with CCNet ? 
I want to deploy automatically Jobs through CCNet.

Answer (score 0):

With BMC Control-M, you can execute your job as a batch.
So yes, you can configure CC.NET to execute a BMC CM task but only if CC.NET & jobs are on the same machine.